# How to upload file to Remote Server by windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

In web App, there is an Input Tag to upload file. In windows phone, It seems it is different. I need hlep on writing HttpWebRequest code to upload file to remote server ( if possible to skydrive). Can you show me how to solve this problem.

1) Upload file from Windows phone.
2) How would I handle the uploaded file on server-side If I use Asp.net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.  I suggest you ask about how to handle it on the server side in its own question with a different set of tags.

```
var uri = "http://example.com/some_applette"
var request = HttpWebRequest.create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";  // Change to whatever you're uploading.
request.BeginGetRequestStream((result1) =>
{
    using (Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result1))
    {
        // Bytes contains the data to upload.
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    request.BeginGetResponse((result2) => 
    {
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(result2);

        // Optionally handle the response.
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        ...
    }
}, null);
```

Comment: This is gr8. Let me work on it and report back later as I need to work on the Server side. People are talking about upload to SkyDrive. can I use Wp7 App to do that?