# How to select a file from disk and upload to server?

Tags: windows-phone-7, file-upload, mobile, windows-mobile, isolatedstorage

How can I select a file from Windows Phone 7 Device disk (`IsolatedStorage` or something other) to upload on a remote server?

> I need to select a PDF from disk and send it to
>   my server.

thanks.

**EDIT 1**:
PDF is already on device. I need to get from disk and send to server.
Is there any file enumeration or something equals to get all?

Comment: More info please. PDF is genereted by your app, come from web servic etc.

Comment: @lukas pdf is already on device. (maybe downloaded from web or other)

Comment: Was it downloaded from your app? If not then it's not going to be in your `IsolatedStorage` for your app is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload file to Remote Server by windows phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209809/how-to-upload-file-to-remote-server-by-windows-phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps can only access their own IsolatedStorage - they cannot access any other files on the device.

So, unless that PDF was retrieved by your app, and saved to IsolatedStorage via your app, your app cannot access it in order to send it out.